# Excel - How to double click a cell and reference another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m wanting to know if this is possible, and how would I go about doing so:

I’d like to be able to double click a cell (in column Z), reference what is in Column G of that same row, and then find and set focus from the info found in column G on another sheet.

So when I double click the cell in Z1 for example, it looks for what information is in G1 and finds it on another sheet and sets focus to that new cell.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what *reference what is in Column G* means? Does it mean that it contains a worksheet name?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear on that. So when I double click the cell in Z1 for example, it looks for what information is in G1 and finds it on another sheet and sets focus to that new cell.

Comment: You can change the contents of your post by using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64739454/edit) button below it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to implement `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event handler then you may do anything you like, handler is an event of Worksheet object. Do your main code in Module code to keep things reusable across multiple sheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = True
  Call Module1.onDrillDownToData(Target)
End Sub
- - - 
Public Function onDrillDownToData(ByRef sender As Range)
  Dim ws as worksheet
  Dim iCol As Long
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim dt As Date

  set ws = sender.Parent
  ' do anything you want with worksheet
  ' sender is the origin cell

  iCol = Sender.Column
  iRow = Sender.Row
  dt = Now()
  ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "'" & Format(dt, "yyyy\-MM\-dd", vbMonday)
  ws.Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).Value = "'" & Format(dt, "hh\:nn\:ss", vbMonday)

  set ws = Application.Worksheets("TargetSheet")
  ws.Activate
  ws.Range("A5").Activate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick

- Copy the following code into the sheet module of the sheet where you are going to double-click (In VBE in the project explorer double-click on the appropriate sheet to open its code window).
- Before exiting VBE, adjust the constants, especially the destination worksheet name (`wsName`, the name in parentheses), in the code.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet2"   ' Destination Worksheet Name
    Const SourceColumn As String = "Z"  ' Source Column String
    Const CriteriaColumn As String = "G"
    
    ' Not sure if this is even possible.
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(SourceColumn)) Is Nothing Then
        Dim Criteria As Variant
        Criteria = Cells(Target.Row, CriteriaColumn)
        If Not IsError(Criteria) And Not IsEmpty(Criteria) Then
            Dim cel As Range
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
                Set cel = .Cells _
                          .Find(What:=Criteria, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                MatchCase:=False) ' Change to True is necessary
                If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                    .Activate
                    cel.Select
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe I’ve changed all the appropriate items you mentioned, code seems to do nothing. Double click still just edits the cells as normal.

Comment: That's happening when clicking in the wrong place. In one sheet you double-click any cell in column Z. Then in the same sheet the code looks for the value in the same row in column G and searches for the whole value in another sheet ("Sheet2" in this case, it's the name in the tabs.) and selects the found cell.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! I had cells in the second sheet pulling info from the first sheet (the criteria in column G) and it wasnt allowing the search to happen I guess. I just transposed the info over instead and it’s working fine.